# Apex salesforce pagereference for URL link mergefield

Tags: report, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

Assuming a link is created and is pointing to a URL with the following pattern:
/00O70000001SOsa?pv0={!Account.Id}&pv1={!Case.IsClosed}
How can this be written in an Apex controller if I have to invoke the same thing using pagereference or any other similar API.

Answer (score 0):

```
// You will have to apply your own logic on how you pick data for the link
Account acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
Case c = [SELECT IsClosed FROM Case LIMIT 1];

Pagereference pr = new PageReference('/00O70000001SOsa');
pr.getParameters().putAll(new Map<String, String>{
    'pv0' => acc.Id,
    'pv1' => c.isClosed ? 'true' : 'false'
});

System.debug(pr.getUrl());
// outputs something like /00O70000001SOsa?pv0=0017000001TSmKmAAL&pv1=false
```

Parameters you pass to the URL have to be Strings (or something that easily casts to String). So it's your job to convert booleans, display dates in format that the other page will "like" (reports need dates in the same format the user would use so according to his/her locale, look at `format` method in Date and DateTime class).

But that's it. You don't have to worry about "?" sign or any fancy escaping of special characters, it'll be done for you:

```
Pagereference pr = new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');
pr.getParameters().putAll(new Map<String, String>{
    'spaces' => 'spa ce',
    'html-entities' => '& < >',
    'percents' => '1 / 4 = 25%'
});

System.debug(pr.getUrl());
// /home/home.jsp?html-entities=%26+%3C+%3E&percents=1+%2F+4+%3D+25%25&spaces=spa+ce
```